# Magento 2.3.2 Error while Compilation

Tags: magento2.3.2, compilation, graphql

I am having this issue after updating Magento from 2.3 to 2.3.2

**Fatal error:**

> Declaration of Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\SetShippingAddressOnCart::execute(Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface $context, Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $cart, array $shippingAddresses):
>
> void must be compatible with Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\SetShippingAddressesOnCartInterface::execute(Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface $context, Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $cart, array $shippingAddressesInput):
>
> void in /my/folder/public_html/app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php on line 20

I can't figure out even what it mean.

**Is it from third-party module conflict or Magento native?**

Any help please?

Comment: Why don't you install Magento via Composer?

Comment: It means that the implementation of the interface has a different return type than the return type specified in the interface

Comment: @vitoriodachef how can I fix it please?

Comment: I suppose you're trying to update from 2.3.0? You should try updating to 2.3.1 first and then to 2.3.2. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @ArnoVandeCappelle I tried that already but from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 I have same issue

Comment: Do you have a solution now? @G.G.

Comment: No. I am still looking into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get the code from? This error should not happen. If you compare your `/my/folder/public_html/app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php` file with the M2 one on [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressesOnCart.php) you will see some difrence.

Comment: From github. I checked the file you mentioned but no luck. Now the error goes to line 15 of ``/my/folder/public_html/app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php``

Comment: I think you should and try to copy the github repo again (the 2.3 branch). Looks like some files have a different version. And also you should use Composer to avoid stuf like this.

Answer (score 3):

Backup and delete the file /vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php

Comment: Actually it needs to remove all these:`/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/ExtractDataFromAddress.php` - `/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/ExtractDataFromCart.php` - `/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/GetCustomerAddress.php` - `/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php` - `/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingMethodOnCart.php` - `/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Cart/CreateEmptyCart.php`